# How to use useEffect Hook to execute the operation only once?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, event-handling

I wanted to make the modal popup if someone leaves the window.

I tried the following code:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    const popupWhenLeave = (event) => {
      if (
        event.clientY <= 0 ||
        event.clientX <= 0 ||
        event.clientX >= window.innerWidth ||
        event.clientY >= window.innerHeight
      ) {
        handleClickOpen();
      }
    };
    document.addEventListener("mouseleave", popupWhenLeave);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mouseleave", popupWhenLeave);
    };
  }, []);
```

The above code helped me but became annoying as it pops up every interval. I tried adding a new state to run the code only once:

```
const [cursorOut, setCursorOut] = useState(false);

React.useEffect(() => {
    const popupWhenLeave = (event) => {
      if (
        event.clientY <= 0 ||
        event.clientX <= 0 ||
        event.clientX >= window.innerWidth ||
        event.clientY >= window.innerHeight
      ) {
        handleClickOpen();
      }
    };
    if(!cursorOut) {
       document.addEventListener("mouseleave", popupWhenLeave);
       setCursorOut(true);
    }

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mouseleave", popupWhenLeave);
    };
  }, []);
```

The above code also ran the same as the previous one i.e. every time the modal would pop up.

I tried to add the dependency to useEffect `[cursorOut]` but now it won't pop the modal.

I need to pop up the modal only once on the page when the cursor is out and then stop.

P.S. I also tried without useEffect and it doesn't work.

Comment: Is you're modal unmounted and therefore reinitialized every time you open it? `useEffect(/**/, [])` (zero dependencies) works perfectly fine but only if the component keeps being mounted

Comment: Would be great if you can replicate same in stackblitz and share here

Comment: I added console log under addEventListener and removeEventListener
ie. console.log("add"); and console.log("remove");
and the output was:

add
remove
add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `useEffect` function *is* only called once, when the dependency array is empty. However, your `useEffect` function adds an event listener to the page, which fill be called *every time the event occurs*.

If you want to only listen to the event once, you should remove the event listener in the `popupWhenLeave` function and not *only* in the `useEffect` clean up function you return at the end.

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const popupWhenLeave = (event) => {
      if (
        event.clientY <= 0 ||
        event.clientX <= 0 ||
        event.clientX >= window.innerWidth ||
        event.clientY >= window.innerHeight
      ) {
        handleClickOpen();
        document.removeEventListener("mouseleave", popupWhenLeave);
      }
    };
    document.addEventListener("mouseleave", popupWhenLeave);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mouseleave", popupWhenLeave);
    };
  }, []);
```

Sidenote: If your component is recreated because e.g. a parent component changed, the `useEffect` function will be called again regardless of the contents of the dependency array.